# Migration data on update app

Tags: android, android-studio, digital-signature, database-migration

I am new in android development. I developed new version of app and want to move data from old version db to new version db, but the problem is that android says firstly uninstall the old app because signature are different.

Answer (score 0):

You have signed your app versions with different keys.

If they were built on different computers, the debug keys are different. If built on the same computer, one is likely a debug key and one a release key.

You cannot update an app unless the app already installed is signed with the same key as the app that is replacing it.

You need to re-sign your app with the same key as the one already installed if you want to update it. The alternative is to uninstall the old app first.

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html